# Can I commit one single SVN diff file instead of committing 10 individual files in one go?

Tags: svn, version-control, diff

I have a list of files that I work on in my source tree in SVN. I might change some other files for my local use and I do not want to commit them. Recently working late by mistake I committed some commented out code that in turn caused some revenue loss to my company and a dent in my credibility. So I created simple bash script that has a list of files I work on and creates a diff for those files. Now I have a diff file, which others may call a patch. Can I commit this SVN diff file somehow to avoid committing all the files? I ssh to a remote box with running RHEL5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, the TortoiseSVN client has a feature that sounds like just what you need: *change lists*. This allows you to separate files into arbitrary groups; the figure shows one called "setup" with all the rest ungrouped ("no changelist").By separating your private changes into their own group it is much easier to avoid inadvertent commits of the files you do not wish to commit.

I talk a bit more about this in [chapter 1](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/subversion-and-tortoisesvn-cookbook-part-1--the-basics/#grouping) of my **TortoiseSVN and Subversion Cookbook**; also see the section on [change lists](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html) in the TortoiseSVN manual.

[image: TortoiseSVN change lists]

*(Image courtesy of TortoiseSVN documentation.)*

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could `svn commit $(<list_of_files.txt)`...